# ref to get element got null in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Not sure am I using ref correctly, basically I want to trigger another element when user clicked on others. But I got error of   `Cannot read property 'photoUploadDropAreaElement' of null`

```
triggerUploadDialog(){
        this.photoUploadDropAreaElement.click();
    }

render() {
    return(
            <div onClick={this.triggerUploadDialog} className="PhotoUploadWrap">
                <PhotoUpload ref={dropArea => this.photoUploadDropAreaElement = dropArea} />
            </div>
    );
```

No syntax error when the page load initially. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Error which you have described actually says that `this` is null (not ref). When you pass event handlers to props you have to bind it to the correct context (`this`). E.g. bind it or use arrow function.

```
<div onClick={this.triggerUploadDialog.bind(this)} className="PhotoUploadWrap">
```

Comment: now I got `this.photoUploadDropAreaElement.click is not a function`

Comment: @GialaJefferson probably `PhotoUpload` component does not expose `click` method. Where this component comes from?